# Axios 400 Bad request in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I have read every issue on here regarding Axios 400 bad request and I can't find a solution. I have a function I am calling during useEffect that firstly gets data from my API and then later based on other factors may need to POST back to the API.

the GET call works perfect, but the POST call keeps failing.

```
const home = match.homeTeam.team_name
const homeScore = null
const away = match.awayTeam.team_name
const awayScore = null
const gameID = match.fixture_id
const result = ""
const points = null
const teamName = userInfo.state.teamName
const date = match.event_date
const status = match.statusShort
const realHomeScore = null
const realAwayScore = null
const homeLogo = match.homeTeam.logo
const awayLogo = match.awayTeam.logo
axios.post('/picks/add/', { home, homeScore, away, awayScore, gameID, result, points, teamName, date, status, realHomeScore, realAwayScore, homeLogo, awayLogo })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

I have checked my payload in Network and it's sending exactly what I want.

I get the following error message in my Catch:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

The route works fine in Postman, and the POSTS I make in there match up exactly with the payload in my requests on the web. But for some reason they fail.

Does this have to do with making two requests to the same API within the same function? My first request is in an Await so it runs and finishes before the rest of the function goes.

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possibly CORS issue? hard to say without the exact error response.

Comment: Just a thought - are there any additional headers in your Postman requests, that you're forgetting to account for in your component? Perhaps your server requires some particular header(s) ?

Comment: I compared those and the only thing off was that Content length was 14 in Postman, which is the amount of parameters and made sense, in the component it was like 108....maybe thats normal but only thing I saw different between the headers

Comment: other thing could be the content-type may not match the actual content. e.g. xxx-form-encoding would need to use querystring, why app/json would need a json object.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could `console.log(error.response)` in your catch block to get a more human-readable object.

Edit: `axios` errors come in three types: `message`, `request` and `response`. To make sure you are handling all possible errors, you could use a conditional block:

```
if (error.response){

//do something

}else if(error.request){

//do something else

}else if(error.message){

//do something other than the other two

}
```

Comment: ughh now I know what it is, one of my inputs isn't correct I guess, which is strange since it worked in Postmam....but atleast I know why now!! I'll work on fixing that now. Thanks!